# Item Selection from list of items By Scrolling Left and Right

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollview, itemscontrol

I want to select next item on scrolling right or left

```
   <StackPanel >
            <StackPanel Width="500">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}" Focusable="False" >

                    <ItemsControl.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}" >
                            <ScrollViewer  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                                           CanContentScroll="True" Template="{DynamicResource ScrollViewerControlTemplate1}" 
                                           helpers:ScrollBarVisibilityHelper.IsEnabled="True" >
                                <ItemsPresenter />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.Template>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Views:DeviceMiniView DataContext="{Binding}" Margin="10,5" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                    Value="0">
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="No devices" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold"
                                                        Margin="0,0,0,20" Foreground="#FFF8F5F5" />
                                                    <TextBlock Text="Click Menu-&gt;Reconnect" FontSize="24"
                                                        FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,0,5,0" Foreground="White" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                    Value="1">
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate />
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ItemsControl.Style>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
```

[image]

I am trying to scroll my item present in scrollViwer, One item once from the list of items, But unfortunately i didn't succeed,
i new with WPF,

I have Xaml:

```
<ItemsControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}" >
        <ScrollViewer  
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
            CanContentScroll="True" 
            Template="{DynamicResource ScrollViewerControlTemplate1}" 
            helpers:ScrollBarVisibilityHelper.IsEnabled="True"
            >
            <ItemsPresenter />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ItemsControl.Template>
```

Can anybody help me out i have tried to change the style, templet and also tried with collectionview and observable collection in view model. 
I would be thankfull.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about what you mean by "one item once from the list of items", and how that relates to the title of your question? Are you saying you want to scroll the items horizontally instead of vertically?

Comment: Thanks, No, i want to select next item when scrolling my item left or right, now when i am scrolling its not selecting next item by it self. i am providing more details, I have added my xaml.

Comment: Why did you revert all the changes to your post?

Comment: By Mistake it happens ,

Comment: Wait, I apologize: It looks like @ManfredRadlwimmer mistakenly edited a stale copy and stepped on a number of changes.

Comment: So how do you think i can achieve my goal???  Ed Plunkett

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that whenever the user scrolls, you want the control's selected item to be the middle item that's visible, is that correct? Unfortunately I don't know any simple way to do that. You'd have to write code.

Comment: I mean to say, whenever user press repeat button to scroll right or left next item should be selected by itself and all the property of next item should be visible.

Comment: At one time properties of one item should be selected, on scrolling next item it should jump to another.

Comment: An `ItemsControl` does not contain selection behavior, so this might be difficult. I'd recommend switching to a `ListBox`, which does contain selection functionality, and overwriting the Template to get the look you want. It's the beauty of "look-less controls" - select the one with the functionality you want, and overwrite the UI to be anything! :)

Comment: Rachel's right, you need a listbox if you want a selected item. When you say "all the property of next item should be visible", I can parse that but I can't interpret it. Please make a picture that shows what it would look like when all the property of next item is visible.

Comment: or maybe somehow it could be achive by Observable collection or icollection view ??

Comment: I wanted to say  on scrolling next, next device selection should be made.

Comment: If the user grabs the horizontal scrollbar and drags to the right by nine items, what happens then? Select next, or select ninth item to the right?

Comment: @EdPlunkett strange, usually the system rejects edits made on older versions or concurrent edits.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I may have misunderstood the change history. If so, I apologize. Whatever happened, it was fixable.

Comment: @EdPlunkett In my project i have to go one by one, repeatedly one and another , By next scrolling i can approach till my item, but i don't understand, how to achive this with list box i have seen few examples and tried. but no luck.